# Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons. Error log record number:

Tags: magento, exception, stack-trace

I just re-installed Magento and restored the old database with PhpMyAdmin.
The front page of the website is OK. But in the backend I've got this error when I go to Manage Categories.

Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.
Error log record number: 986836145855

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: The number is random and is a `var/report/` file name. Please find the stack trace file and ask another question pertinent to "Manage Categories" and the error contained in the Report file.

Answer (score 1):

Go to `magento/var/report` and open the file with the Error log record number name (986836145855 in your case).

In that file you can find the complete description of the error.

For log files like `system.log` and `exception.log`, go to `magento/var/log/`.